# Cytoscape for Angular (Node) - Horizontal Scaling Issues

Tags: javascript, html, angular, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am new to this forum and Cytoscape.JS in general - please bear with me!

I have an application I am developing inside of Angular using the Node Cytoscape.JS package. The cy graph is rendered within an angular card - the card is 50% of the width of the screen, but the Cytoscape element inside is allowed to take up the entirety of the card contents.

I have a dataset with a few hundred nodes using the "cose" layout. The issue we have is the rendered graph only shows up as a column inside the center of the card, taking maybe 50% of the available space (center justified). If I grab the graph render and slide it, it'll move into the open space, so I know that Cy is able to access it.

The hope is to get the graph to spread itself, widthwise, to fill the entire space it is allowed - then from there span down past the lower boundaries of the card (into the scroll area). Doing some research, I found that the "spread" layout may be a better direction to go, but after installing the package and setting up the required elements, I was met with nothing but errors. If anyone can help me with that, I'm open as well!

Currently we are trying to manipulate the layout object to fit 100% width - that object is below. Nothing in CSS or JS has made a difference. If anyone has ideas please let me know! Thank you!

```
cy = cytoscape({
            container: cy_container,
            elements: this.elements,
            layout: {
                name: 'cose',
                // rankDir: 'LR',
                directed: true,
                padding: 0
            },
            style: this.styleSheet,
           
           
        });
```

Comment: the layout is probably unrelated. The canvas should take the designated space. Here you can color the canvas and see the space it is taking and giving absolute width height values to the cytoscape.js container div might be necessary

Comment: @canbax I appreciate the input, I tried adding a background color to the underlying Cytoscape object and it filled in the entire available area with that color, though the nodes are still showing centered.

Comment: then the issue is with layout ;)